# Consume data from Peoplesoft with Integration Broker

Tags: rest, web-services, peoplesoft

Hello i was thinking of how to get data through (***rest API***) from Peoplesoft after it consume in a 3rd party app i have developed apart.

I have read about **INTEGRATION BROKER** would be ideal. But not sure how to do the setup.

Basically I want to consume names from DB through web-services.

Would it be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago, my friend Hakan created documentation to help customers implement integration broker. You can find a link here: https://blog.jsmpros.com/2013/01/how-to-configure-and-use-integration.html